# How can I retrive a value from this json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script>
var output = {"regions":{"4441":"Avtonomna Respublika Krym","4431":"Cherkas'ka Oblast'","4432":"Chernihivs'ka Oblast'","4433":"Chernivets'ka Oblast'","4434":"Dnipropetrovs'ka Oblast'","4435":"Donets'ka Oblast'","4436":"Ivano-Frankivs'ka Oblast'","4437":"Kharkivs'ka Oblast'","4438":"Khersons'ka Oblast'","4439":"Khmel'nyts'ka Oblast'","4440":"Kirovohrads'ka Oblast'","4443":"Kyyivs'ka Oblast'","4445":"L'vivs'ka Oblast'","4444":"Luhans'ka Oblast'","4442":"Misto Kyyiv","4450":"Misto Sevastopol","4446":"Mykolayivs'ka Oblast'","4447":"Odes'ka Oblast","4448":"Poltavs'ka Oblast'","4449":"Rivnens'ka Oblast'","4451":"Sums'ka Oblast'","4452":"Ternopil's'ka Oblast'","788":"Ukraine","4453":"Vinnyts'ka Oblast'","4454":"Volyns'ka Oblast'","4455":"Zakarpats'ka Oblast'","4456":"Zaporiz'ka Oblast'","4457":"Zhytomyrs'ka Oblast'"}}

alert(output.regions[1]);
</script>
```

This part gives me undefined:

```
alert(output.regions[1]);
```

How can I grab the first key/value pair for example. Basically I need to turn this into a select dropdown, the numeric keys would be the values and the names of the cities would be the option text.

Comment: Just a side note that what you're trying to access is a JavaScript object, not a JSON object. JSON is a _representation_ of the object (i.e. the characters which you pasted above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can iterate over it like:

```
for(key in output.regions) { 
    alert(key +' => '+output.regions[key]);  // 4441 => Avtonomna Respublika Krym  ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a numeric index, you'll want to key into `regions` with the keys you've specified, like `4441`, `4431`, etc:

```
var output = {"regions":{"4441":"Avtonomna Respublika Krym","4431":"Cherkas'ka Oblast'","4432":"Chernihivs'ka Oblast'","4433":"Chernivets'ka Oblast'","4434":"Dnipropetrovs'ka Oblast'","4435":"Donets'ka Oblast'","4436":"Ivano-Frankivs'ka Oblast'","4437":"Kharkivs'ka Oblast'","4438":"Khersons'ka Oblast'","4439":"Khmel'nyts'ka Oblast'","4440":"Kirovohrads'ka Oblast'","4443":"Kyyivs'ka Oblast'","4445":"L'vivs'ka Oblast'","4444":"Luhans'ka Oblast'","4442":"Misto Kyyiv","4450":"Misto Sevastopol","4446":"Mykolayivs'ka Oblast'","4447":"Odes'ka Oblast","4448":"Poltavs'ka Oblast'","4449":"Rivnens'ka Oblast'","4451":"Sums'ka Oblast'","4452":"Ternopil's'ka Oblast'","788":"Ukraine","4453":"Vinnyts'ka Oblast'","4454":"Volyns'ka Oblast'","4455":"Zakarpats'ka Oblast'","4456":"Zaporiz'ka Oblast'","4457":"Zhytomyrs'ka Oblast'"}}

alert(output.regions[4441]); // alerts "Avtonomna Respublika Krym"
```

Answer (score 1):

The regions entity is an object and not an array so you have to select its attribute by its associated key.

```
output.regions.4441
```

or

```
output.regions['4441']
```

Comment: Or you can iterate over it like what nav said

Answer (score 1):

The value with the key "regions" is a map, not an array - it has no ordering, therefore there is no concept of "first key/value pair" - you'll have to impose your own ordering if you want one.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `output.regions` is an object, not an array. You would either need to access by the ID (778) or if you don't know it, than you can iterate to find it.

```
for (k in output.regions) { var key = k; break; }
alert(output.regions[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "first" value. Properties of javascript objects are not ordered. You can iterate over a javascript object like this:

```
for(key in output.regions){
   alert(output.regions[key])
}
```

and check for the cycle of iteration, but there's no guarantee that the order won't change unexpectedly. To have a guaranteed order, you need to use an array.